# Chrome-extension "Cannot read property 'onUpdated' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a script which I want to inject to a page every 10 seconds.
I use this code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,tab){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"program.js"});
  }
);
```

program.js looks like this:

```
$("body").prepend("Hello World!");  
setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},10000);
```

Meaning every 10 seconds the page should refresh itself and inject this piece of code, it works ok, but sometimes (especially when running more than one tab) I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onUpdated' of undefined
```

I'm guessing its not getting the tabId or something.
But I can't solve it.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why `null` as first arguement? If you don't want it you can skip it, its optional I think.

Comment: Thanks, I did so but still, same error.

Comment: Where are you writing this code? In a background script or content script?

Comment: Background script (background.js)

Comment: If it occurs only sometimes for more tabs and works other times, then it may be a bug.

Comment: That's what I thought. I'll try and use a diffrent method of closing and reopening the tab and hopefully it'll work.

Comment: I've seen this bug many times, but can't reproduce it so I never report it. I've only ever seen it in development and unpacked. Especially when I'm using the reload button a lot.

Comment: Hm, is the background page defined with `"persistent": false` by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem only with `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener` and chrome would complain about `onMessageExternal`. Like @scott-f pointed out the reason for this bug is 'abusing' th reload button. I removed and reinstalled the extension and it worked.

In hindsight I would suggest you use the `--load-extensions='extension/path'` from the cli to test your extension with the mouse just to avoid the overhead of navigating around chrome's menus, and use Selenium to automate your tests.